# Paginating from multiple div classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

**MAJOR EDIT**

So I have it working now, well, sort of.  I needed to use the AJAX example from the jQuery Pagination Plugin with a jQuery.noConflict statement.  Here is the code:

```
            jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
        function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
            var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
            $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
            return false;
        }

        /** 
         * Callback function for the AJAX content loader.
         */
        function initPagination() {
            var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
            // Create pagination element
            $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
                num_edge_entries: 2,
                num_display_entries: 8,
                callback: pageselectCallback,
                items_per_page:1
            });
         }

        // Load HTML snippet with AJAX and insert it into the Hiddenresult element
        // When the HTML has loaded, call initPagination to paginate the elements        
        $(document).ready(function(){      
            $('#hiddenresult').load('snippet.html', null, initPagination);
        });
        });
```

This is working well, it loads a snippet while it waits for the JSON to be passed to the page.  My problem now is I can change the pagination options.  The default shows only three results.  I want to show 10 results per page.  If I try and change the items_per_page the pagination disappears and only the snippet result shows. Is it possible to show 10 and paginate?  What happens if there are less that 10 results?

Thanks in advance!

**ORGINAL QUESTION**

So this is another n00b question and I am not sure if the best way to do this will be using PHP or jQuery?  I can at least read jQuery, even if my writing of it is basically non-existant, but my PHP understanding is getting much better, again, no writing though.

Basically I have a JSON object that is being converted to a 'list' of div class items within an overall div id wrap.  I need to be able to paginate the results.  The example I have here is only 10 items but I have one object that is returning 250 items.

The jQuery returning the JSON is working spot on, now just to get it to paginate within the same page.

Currently the HTML output looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="dealer_limpopo">
    <div class="dealer">
        <dl>
            <dt>
                Company Name
            </dt>
            <dd>
                Cable-Tech
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Company Description
            </dt>
            <dd>
                Computer &amp; Software Sales Licensing Network Infrasture Solutions
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Email Address
            </dt>
            <dd>
                Isaacm@cable-tech.co.za
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Contact Number
            </dt>
            <dd>
                084 688 9457
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Website URL
            </dt>
            <dd>
                http://www.cable-tech.co.za
            </dd>
            <dt>
                City
            </dt>
            <dd>
                Polokwane
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Physical Address
            </dt>
            <dd>
                Factory 39/No.06, Freedom Drive, Industrial Area, Seshego, 0742
            </dd>
        </dl>
    <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    <div class="dealer">
                 .....
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

You can see the page live at http://thegearbox.co/thisisatest/

The question is? How does one paginate the results?  I have tried to use [jQuery Pagination Plugin](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination) but I really can't get around the script in there?

I really am just starting out learning scripting and other client side languages... Got tossed in the deep end a little though, so any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Eg: To have 2 items per page and 3 links in pagination :

```
function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
                $('#Searchresult').empty();
                // replace "2" per the item_per_page value in the "for" statement below
                for(var i=page_index*2;i<((page_index*2)+2);i++) {
                    var new_content = jQuery('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+i+')').clone();
                    $('#Searchresult').append(new_content);
                }
                return false;
            }
            /** 
             * Initialisation function for pagination
             */
            function initPagination() {
                // count entries inside the hidden content
                var num_entries = jQuery('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
                // Create content inside pagination element
                $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
                    callback: pageselectCallback,
                    items_per_page:2, // Show only 2 item per page
                    num_edge_entries:3, // 3 pager links
                });
             }
 // When document is ready, initialize pagination
            $(document).ready(function(){      
                initPagination();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the demo sample (demo.htm) you have to put each 
`'<div class="dealer">'` 
into an another div. Like this :

```
<div id="hiddenresult" style="display:none;"><div class="dealer">...</div><div class="dealer">...</div> ...</div>
```

Then you add a div where you will display page content. Like this :

```
<div id="Searchresult">Your page content will be displayed here</div>
```

Then you add your div where your pagination will be displayed :

```
<div id="Pagination"></div>
```

In you javascript section you add this code :

```
// the function called for each click on a pager item
function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
                // find the next element to display in '#hiddenresult' div
                var new_content = jQuery('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();

                // will add the next content to the '#Searchresult' div
                $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
                return false;
            }

$(document).ready(function(){ 
           // num_entries is the number of 'dealer' object you will use
           $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
                    callback: pageselectCallback,
                    items_per_page:1 // Show only one item per page
            });
});
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out... just been called into a meeting, but as soon as I get back I'll try this out...

Comment: I have just tried this line and I am being through the following error by Chrome Dev Tools - Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function - just below the $(document).ready(function(){ line.  Not sure what this means, but no results show :/ its on http://thegearbox.co/thisisatest/

Comment: It seems that you dont have jquery declaration in your page.
Add this line your "<head></head>" section : 
"<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>"

jQuery is a framework for javascript. I recommend you to learn it.
http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: It is there, first line of the script.  As I mentioned I am trying to learn client side languages at the moment :) Is it possible because the hidden div is being populated from a JSON object? so the data is not there when the page loads?  It only gets populated later?

Comment: Ok. I forgot to close the "ready" method. I've edited my answer above.

If it doesnt resolve your problem, try to put "$ = jQuery.noConflict();" in your javascript section. 

I dont think that the problem come from the fact that you hidde the div but try to use with already populated div if you have a doubt.

Comment: Ok, so the noConflict line worked, I needed to put jQuery.noConflict()(function($){ in to make it work... I am loading data now, I am going to update my question so you can see what is going on.  I had to use the ajax example to make it work.  Problem is now I can't view more than 3 entries (I know there has to be a setting for this).  Also I want to show 10 results per page. I'll show you the code in the question above. Thanks again for all the help, you are a legend!